# app structuring / re importing modules with tkinter python3

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I am restructuring this question:  I felt the original questions were long winded and not particularly helpful to anyone else.

I have a main app (run as__main__) that runs directly.
I have a module (simple_module.py) that I only wish to use as an import.
I realise that I can run it standalone if required (via if__name__) and have including that in the modules code, for demonstration only.

When user presses main.py's 'start' button, it should open a new toplevel window with all the classes and widgets from the simple_module which are all in a single class called Page. (all whilst the main app window remains open.)

I want the module to be re-imported (or equivalent) every time the button is pressed.  When the modules 'close' button or X is pressed I want it to close that window.  main.py's window remains open throughout this and the button press needs to re-open that module window, infinitely, like a loop.

I have added if **name** == '**main**' just to highlight that I understand what this does (it is normally within all my main.py apps) and why I still cannot get the result I want.  As far as I can see, it does not change anything, I am now only importing the class but 'new' is still not recognised.  Which is the same issue as in the prior example.

I have main.py

```
import tkinter as tk

# audio module works as expected
import audio_module as am

# I want this window to open and close on command
import simple_module as sm



class GUI(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        #self.new = tk.Toplevel(self) # auto loads a second, unwanted window

        self.session_counter = 0
        self.start_btn = tk.Button(root, text="start", command=self.start)
        self.start_btn.grid(row=4,column=0,sticky="nsew",pady=30, padx=30, ipady=18)


    def start(self):
        am.spell() # these audio imports work like a charm, every btn press - single functions call OK

        self.session_counter += 1
        print(self.session_counter)

        #import simple_module - if used here, my usual 'illegal' import style (works great, once only,
        # unless in same script as __main__ in which case all re-imports work fine)

        # Import attempts
        #import simple_module as sm
        #page = Page(new) # Page not defined
        #sm.Page() #missing parent arg (new)

        # error: 'new' not defined
        #sm.Page(new)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('running as __main__')
    root = tk.Tk()
    #sm.Page = tk.Toplevel(new) # a desperate attempt NO
    #page = sm.Page(tk.TopLevel) NO
    # qualify and USE module here! sm is not required if you use 'from simple_module import Page' !!
    page = sm.Page(root)
    #page.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    page.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')
    main = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Finally, we have simple_module.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
import audio_module as am

# this module works exactly as expected IF run directly...

class Page(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        # super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.back_btn = tk.Button(parent, text="close", command=self.back)
        self.back_btn.grid(row=4,column=0,sticky="nsew",pady=30, padx=30, ipady=18)


    def back(self):
        am.click()
        # close this page BUT have it ready to re-open IF user re-presses button.
        new.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('running as __main__ directly')
    new = tk.Tk()
    #new = tk.Toplevel() # this loads an unwanted additional blank window. IF run directly.
    page = Page(new)
    # the missing line to self contain module!
    #page.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    page.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')
    new.mainloop()

else:
    print('running as import with __name__ ==',__name__)
```

Thanks for your patience and responses.  I have re-studied the if **main** guide you provided a link to, it re-affirms what I already believe I knew about it.  A useful example in there for when I want to open a single frame only and switch between them, but in this case I want the main window to remain open whilst calling the modules window.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is that your `Page` class isn't written to be reusable. It's relying on global variables and knowledge about the code that is calling it. To be reusable, the `Page` class needs to be self-contained.

In short, that means that every widget created by `Page` must be inside the `Page` class and not in the root window. Also, the code that creates an instance of `Page` needs to be responsible for calling `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on the instance.

So, the first step is to modify `Page` so that it can be reusable. The key to that is to require that the caller pass in the parent widget. You're doing that, but you aren't using the passed-in value.

`Page` should look like the following code. Notice that it explicitly declares `parent` as the first positional argument, and it passes that on to `tk.Frame.__init__`:

```
class Page(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.back_btn = tk.Button(parent, text="close", command=self.back)
        ...
```

Notice how the back button is a child of `parent` rather than the child of some global variable. This is the important step that you are missing, and this is what allows `Page` to be self-contained and not tightly coupled to the code that creates it.

Once `Page` is properly self-contained, it is the responsibility of the code that creates an instance of `Page` to call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on the instance.

For example, `simple_module.py` might have this block at the end:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    new = tk.Tk()
    page = Page(new)
    page.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    new.mainloop()
```

In main.py, since you are importing `simple_module` as a whole, you need to fully qualify the use of `Page`:

```
import simple_module as sm
...
root = tk.Tk()
page = sm.Page(root)
page.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Alternately, you could just import `Page` and omit the `sm.`:

```
from simple_module import Page
...
page = Page(root)
...
```

Notice how one file can use `root` and one can use `new`, but your code will work in either case because it doesn't rely on a global variable. Inside of page it will always be `parent` no matter what the caller called it.

As an aside, you don't have to import `simple_module` inside `start` -- you only need to import it once at the start of the program.

Comment: Thanks Mr Oakley.  I have been trying to tackle the issue unsuccessfully so I have re written the post to be more targeted .  I do hope you can offer further help.

Comment: OK, interesting developments.  I cannot use .pack() since its enslaved by .grid().  I cannot load the second window on Start button?  I have tried changing it from pack to grid, but that module window will not load.  If page.pack() or .grid() is within the outer if statement - then why would it be enslaved? Nearly there, just need the second window to open.  I thought TopLevel would be involved also, yet you haven't included it.

Comment: @glitchyGhost: pack is not "enslaved" by grid. I don't even know what that means. They are independent of each other.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_simple.py", line 76, in <module>
    page.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2387, in pack_configure
    self.tk.call(

_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid

Comment: @glitchyGhost: yes, that's what happens when you misuse `grid` and `pack`. That usually means you're doing something wrong. It sounds like you didn't follow the advice in this answer and make each page  self-contained. You can't use both `pack` and `grid` for widgets that have the same parent. It has nothing to do with the use of classes. You can get that error with or without classes.